Bitcoin Core linking error
I'm trying to build Bitcoin Source code v24.2 for Windows using WSL running Ubuntu (latest). I'm following the instructions instructions given the /doc/build-windows.md. I got linker errors:
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: libbitcoin_node.a(libbitcoin_node_a-txindex.o):txindex.cpp:(.text+0x3009): undefined reference to `node::OpenBlockFile(FlatFilePos const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: libbitcoin_node.a(libbitcoin_node_a-coinstats.o):coinstats.cpp:(.text+0x13fc): undefined reference to `node::BlockManager::LookupBlockIndex(uint256 const&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: libbitcoin_zmq.a(libbitcoin_zmq_a-zmqpublishnotifier.o):zmqpublishnotifier.cpp:(.text+0x4c3d): undefined reference to `node::ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock&, CBlockIndex const*, Consensus::Params const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:7029: bench/bench_bitcoin.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/madguy/BitcoinSetup/bitcoin/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:18981: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/madguy/BitcoinSetup/bitcoin/src'
make: *** [Makefile:824: all-recursive] Error 1
root@MadGuy:/home/madguy/BitcoinSetup/bitcoin# grep -r "ReadBlockFromDisk" .

I did:
root@MadGuy:/home/madguy/BitcoinSetup/bitcoin# grep -r "ReadBlockFromDisk" .

and got (and some more):
./src/node/blockstorage.h:bool ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock& block, const FlatFilePos& pos, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams);
./src/node/blockstorage.h:bool ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock& block, const CBlockIndex* pindex, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams);
./src/node/blockstorage.cpp:bool ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock& block, const FlatFilePos& pos, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams)

which means the headers and definitions exist (same goes for OpenBlockFile(...)). But they've no preprocessors either, I'm not sure what can cause this issue. Please help, it's kinda urgent.

Hi Ahsan, v24.2 has reached EOL earlier this year, is there a reason you're not building a more recent version? And do you really need to build from source as opposed to using the pre-built release binary?

@VojtěchStrnad Thank you, man!! At least you replied. But I solved it. I wasn't following any of the provided instructions in bitcoin/build_windows.md. In fact, I didn't everything is automated; I love that repo. Someone else asked for help, it wasn't mine.
THANK YOU, I don't know why. But I'm feeling good today. Hope you also have a good day.

@VojtěchStrnad and you didn't get mad like some other nerdies setting in the basement.

Fellow person with the same problem.
If you're building while not following the provided documentation at bitcoin/doc/build_windows.md or any platform whatsoever. You should follow whatever instructions are given in bitcoin/doc. You'll need cmake and libtool-bin and execute any libtool commands given as warnings during dependency build or you'll have to juggle (I don't know what this word means) errors.
